# Adminer for Accumulo

Tags: accumulo

The default Accumulo mointor allows to check the status of the servers and scans. As far as I know it does neither offer a way to see actual data nor does it allow to perform actions such as insertion, updates or deletions.

For many databases there are web interfaces which offer this, such as [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/de/) or [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/). Is there any project which offers something like that for Accumulo?

Answer (score 4):

If you enable the Accumulo monitor to run with SSL (http://accumulo.apache.org/1.7/accumulo_user_manual.html), you can access the Accumulo shell through your Web browser.

Comment: Well, this is good to know, but actually I was looking for something more graphical, which is easier to use for people who are not used to work with the shell.

Comment: Sorry, that's all that we have right now. As long as we can be sure of the security, I'm sure we'd be receptive of such a UI if you'd like to build such a tool. :)

Comment: Till april there won't be the time for this. But if I find some time, I will let you now